# Automatically mounted NTFS (not in /etc/fstab) won't chmod

Tags: ntfs, fstab, chmod

I have an NTFS partition so I can share with a dual-booted Windows installation. `chmod` doesn't do anything, nor issue a warning to indicate this.

I want other (Ubuntu) users to have RW permissions on certain files.

```
brian@brian-t1:/media/Storage/Documents/Scratch Projects$ ls -l    
-rw------- 1 brian brian      5 2012-01-11 02:18 testfile
brian@brian-t1:/media/Storage/Documents/Scratch Projects$ chmod go+rw testfile
brian@brian-t1:/media/Storage/Documents/Scratch Projects$ ls -l
-rw------- 1 brian brian      5 2012-01-11 02:18 testfile
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - I would use a Linux native file system as NTFS is likely to get complicated and may not work.

If you *must* use ntfs, mount the ntfs partition with the option permissions.

Edit `/etc/fstab`

```
# Graphical 
gksu gedit /etc/fstab

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/fstab
```

Add an entry

```
/dev/sda2  /media/ntfs ntfs-3g  permissions,locale=en_US.utf8   0   2
```

chown and chmod will now work.

However ...

1. My understanding is Microsoft made some changes to ntfs and some people report they can not read files written to a NTFS drive from Ubuntu.
2. You may well need to map users. See http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I was tearing my hair out on this one until I found out about the lack of support on NTFS.  I had followed the suggestions of a user who had shown how to have win & Ubuntu live side by side & they had the storage shared drive as NTFS.  I live and learn.

Comment: I've seen newer answers with different techniques. Just wondering if you'd like to modernize this ~7 year old answer or leave as is?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix as far as I know it still works, did you find a problem ?

Comment: @Panther not sure, I used a different answer you posted on another thread: `UUID=5CCC5867CC583E08 /mnt/c ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8  0 2`

Comment: Those are not bad options =)